# mnist_784 download fails with CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED (Even after installing certifi)

Tags: python, macos, ssl, ssl-certificate, mnist

I am trying to run the following command:

```
fetch_openml('mnist_784')
```

from the `sklearn` library.
I keep getting the following error message:
`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>`

I searched online and tried running `pip install certifi` and running `open /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command` from the terminal.
Both actions completed successfully yet I still receive the same error.
I am using Python 3.6.8 an MacOs 10.15.7

Output from `pip install certifi`:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2020.11.8)
-- removing any existing file or link
-- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
-- setting permissions
-- update complete
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern in the future:

I was able to find the root cause of this issue- I was using a proxy (Zscaler) which causes an issue with the CA certificates. Once the proxy was disabled I was able to run my code smoothly